# trying to move value of cells in column to another based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code below and what I am trying to do search `column D` and if there is **no value** then take the value in `column c` and put it in `column D`.

Unfortunately, when I run this it just deletes everything in column C.

```
Sub CleanReportStep10() 
'align columns C and D realign columns by moving data from C to D'
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("copied") 
Dim i As Long

For i = 19 To ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If ws.Range("D" & i) = "" Then
        ws.Range("C" & i).Copy.Value = ws.Range("D" & i).Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you statement to

```
ws.Range("D" & i).Value = ws.Range("C" & i).Value
```

---

Looping through a range may be a little quicker in this instance. Also, toggling of `ScreenUpdating` to make this cleaner from a user stand point

```
Option Explicit

Sub Alternative()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("copied")
Dim LRow As Long, MyCell As Range

LRow = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each MyCell In ws.Range("C19:C" & LRow)
        If MyCell.Offset(, 1) = "" Then MyCell.Offset(, 1).Value = MyCell.Value
    Next MyCell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```